# EF Migrations - how to manage during dev and deployment?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

We're considering using EF 4.3.1 code-based migrations, but aren't clear about how to integrate Migrations with our present dev/deployment methodology...

The app in-question is a desktop WPF app, with each desktop having its own SQL Server instance (each with 4 separate databases). It is deployed into a "field"  environment with zero local IT support. Any database migration must be done using SQL scripts executed by the installer (probably InstallShield). There will not be anyone available who can run a command at a PMC prompt to upgrade the db when it is deployed/upgraded at a field location. Thus the ultimate "output" from EF Migrations must be a set of SQL scripts, which the installer will selectively apply.

Also, we have multiple developers making concurrent database changes.. there is NO DBA.  Each developer simply checks-in their code (model) changes to TFS, and the next time they do get-latest, the changes to the model automatically cause a new database to be created on their dev system. So how can we now have each developer perform their own local migrations (rather than deleting/recreating their local databases), and then manage/consolidate/combine those migrations? And what about collisions?

During dev and unit-testing, each developer may delete their (entire) local database multiple times during a single checkout/checkin iteration.  This works great with Code First, since the database gets automatically rebuilt when the app is restarted. But this means that the _MigrationHistory table in the database also gets deleted.  How do we handle this?  Don't we need the migration history of each dev system? If not, then where/how do we detect the aggregate changes which need to be applied to the delivered system?

I can see the value of using Migrations to deal with the mechanics of migrating a database, but what's not clear is how to take advantage of it without introducing a centralized database "change-control" bottleneck into the dev cycle, and thus losing one of the key benefits of Code First.

Any insight/advice would be greatly appreciated!

DadCat

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I thought I'd post some of my experiences with EF Migrations (v6.1).

Each dev will be fine. Migrations are put into classes with a timestamp in the name, so no collisions will happen. The DB on the dev's machine will be updated after doing a get latest and running the app (or the update-database command).

Deleting the local db and recreating is fine. Just make sure the dev runs update-database before adding additional migrations or things will get out of sync. I'm a bit confused as to why they'd need to delete the local DB, but that's out of scope. You may find that your process needs to change to accommodate EF Migrations.

I can't help you with the installer question, as a similar question brought me here. The update-database command does have a -script option that will generate the proper change script, but I'm unclear how to automate that on a build server.